# Mysql 5.5 IF statement

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

Using Mysql 5.5. Trying to use IF statement:

```
mysql> SELECT description IF(1=1,'ok','no') FROM my_table;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF(1=1,'ok','no') FROM my_table at line 1
```

Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct syntax of **[IF()](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx)** in mysql query is:

```
SELECT IF(condition, 'Some Result If True', 'Some Result If False'), OTHER_COLUMNS
FROM ...
WHERE ...
```

so you should use

```
SELECT description,IF(1=1,'ok','no') FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 3):

As a technical note, this is the `if()` *function*, not the `if` statement.  In any case, you are just missing a comma:

```
SELECT description, IF(1=1,'ok','no')
------------------^
FROM my_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

**Assumming you want description ='yes' for 1=1 otherwise no**

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN 1=1 THEN 'ok' ELSE 'no' END as description
```